# Looping through each worksheet looking for data and returning it to specific sheet if its there

Tags: vba, excel

For the background on what I am creating it is a workbook to track projects. Right now I have 3 projects in my workbook but this number will be over 50 and growing. Each sheet contains project information [Project info Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o2o5.png) . The code I have doesn't work right now. This picture shows what I want it to feed to [All projects page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDFPj.png) this all projects page. What I want the code to do is read through each sheet and if $A$5 = "Project # :" is true then it will copy specified cells from that sheet to the all projects page. Then goes to the next sheet and does the same and if its true again, puts the values 1 row below the last one.

I guess what I was saying was a little unclear, here is the Code I'm currently using to get the output I want and have on the "All Projects" Page in the photo:

```
Sub All_Data()

'Sheet "1"
Sheet7.Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$1" 'classifying number
Sheet7.Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$B$5" 'Project #
Sheet7.Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$A$1" 'Project Name
Sheet7.Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$B$8" 'Project Engineer
Sheet7.Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$B$6" 'Maximo Time Charge
Sheet7.Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$5" 'Material Forecast due date
Sheet7.Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$11" 'Materials Forecast Actual
Sheet7.Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$11" 'Forecast success
Sheet7.Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$12" 'Non Stores Success
Sheet7.Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$6" '30% Due
Sheet7.Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$13" '30% actual
Sheet7.Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$13" '30% success
Sheet7.Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$7" '60% due
Sheet7.Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$14" '60% actual
Sheet7.Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$14" '60% Success
Sheet7.Range("P2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$8" '90% due
Sheet7.Range("Q2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$15" '90% actual
Sheet7.Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$15" '90% success
Sheet7.Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$B$11" 'In-service Due
Sheet7.Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$E$16" 'In-service actual
Sheet7.Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=1!$F$16" 'In-service Success


'Sheet "2"
Sheet7.Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$1" 'classifying number
Sheet7.Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$B$5" 'Project #
Sheet7.Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$A$1" 'Project Name
Sheet7.Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$B$8" 'Project Engineer
Sheet7.Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$B$6" 'Maximo Time Charge
Sheet7.Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$5" 'Material Forecast due date
Sheet7.Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$11" 'Materials Forecast Actual
Sheet7.Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$11" 'Forecast success
Sheet7.Range("I3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$12" 'Non Stores Success
Sheet7.Range("J3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$6" '30% Due
Sheet7.Range("K3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$13" '30% actual
Sheet7.Range("L3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$13" '30% success
Sheet7.Range("M3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$7" '60% due
Sheet7.Range("N3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$14" '60% actual
Sheet7.Range("O3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$14" '60% Success
Sheet7.Range("P3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$8" '90% due
Sheet7.Range("Q3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$15" '90% actual
Sheet7.Range("R3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$15" '90% success
Sheet7.Range("S3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$B$11" 'In-service Due
Sheet7.Range("T3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$E$16" 'In-service actual
Sheet7.Range("U3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=2!$F$16" 'In-service Success



'Sheet "3"
Sheet7.Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$1" 'classifying number
Sheet7.Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$B$5" 'Project #
Sheet7.Range("C4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$A$1" 'Project Name
Sheet7.Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$B$8" 'Project Engineer
Sheet7.Range("E4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$B$6" 'Maximo Time Charge
Sheet7.Range("F4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$5" 'Material Forecast due date
Sheet7.Range("G4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$11" 'Materials Forecast Actual
Sheet7.Range("H4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$11" 'Forecast success
Sheet7.Range("I4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$12" 'Non Stores Success
Sheet7.Range("J4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$6" '30% Due
Sheet7.Range("K4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$13" '30% actual
Sheet7.Range("L4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$13" '30% success
Sheet7.Range("M4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$7" '60% due
Sheet7.Range("N4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$14" '60% actual
Sheet7.Range("O4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$14" '60% Success
Sheet7.Range("P4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$8" '90% due
Sheet7.Range("Q4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$15" '90% actual
Sheet7.Range("R4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$15" '90% success
Sheet7.Range("S4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$B$11" 'In-service Due
Sheet7.Range("T4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$E$16" 'In-service actual
Sheet7.Range("U4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=3!$F$16" 'In-service Success

End Sub
```

With this code I am able to assign each value to the correct place, but all that is changing from each on is the sheet number in the formula, and the row changes.

Sheet7.Range("**U4**").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=**3!**$F$16" 'In-service Success

IS there a way I can write some sort of loop that will go through each sheet, take the specified data from the "project info" sheets and move it to the "all projects" sheet and each new sheet is assigned a new row. Each project sheet contains the same info in the same cell locations.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job.

```
Sub allProjdata()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Clear previous data on the All projects page
        .Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" Then
                x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                '.Cells(x, "A").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$1"    'classifying number
                .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name

                .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$5"    'Project #
                .Cells(x, "C").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$1"    'Project Name
                .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$8"    'Project Engineer
                .Cells(x, "E").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$6"    'Maximo Time Charge
                .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$5"    'Material Forecast due date
                .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11"    'Materials Forecast Actual
                .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$11"    'Forecast success
                .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$12"    'Non Stores Success
                .Cells(x, "J").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$6"    '30% Due
                .Cells(x, "K").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$13"    '30% actual
                .Cells(x, "L").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$13"    '30% success
                .Cells(x, "M").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$7"    '60% due
                .Cells(x, "N").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$14"    '60% actual
                .Cells(x, "O").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$14"    '60% Success
                .Cells(x, "P").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$8"    '90% due
                .Cells(x, "Q").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$15"    '90% actual
                .Cells(x, "R").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$15"    '90% success
                .Cells(x, "S").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11"    'In-service Due
                .Cells(x, "T").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$16"    'In-service actual
                .Cells(x, "U").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$16"    'In-service Success
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I adjusted my code and question a little bit, could you re-read my question and sampled code and see if you see a way to do my code better so it automatically goes through the sheets and I don't have to copy and paste my code and change the sheet and row. I did that for the code above but I plan to have over 50 projects and to copy and paste that and change 2 values for each line will take some serious time

Comment: Basically you're linking the cells from each of the `Project info Worksheet s` to rows on the All projects page.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Text "Project # :" is in cell `A5` not in `B5`

Comment: @xmojmr Good catch.  Thanks!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for thank you very much! One last thing I could add just to make my worksheet a little more efficient, for the very first formula where it's looking for the classifying number, instead of it pulling that classifying number how would I code that to just put the name of the worksheet instead. (Right now I manually input that number on each sheet and all it is, is the worksheet name.) If I can just make that first one referencing the sheets name instead of $F$1 that would be better.

Comment: Change `.Cells(x, "A").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$1"` to `.Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name`.  I updated it in my answer.

Comment: I have one last thing I want to understand , the format of code     .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$12"  I don't understrand If I wanted to exchange the $F$12 for a different formula that's not just a cell reference how would I do that, lets say I wanted to make it a =COUNTIF(G19:G121,"*") and still on ws,name , I tried changing it but could not figure it out.

Comment: How could I changed it to do what I said in my last comment, I updated the comment.

Comment: The formulas get a little tricky when they contain double quotation marks.  Read [Quotation marks within quotes](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-17.html) .  You can use a string literal `.Cells(x, "I").Formula = """=COUNTIF(G19:G121,""*"")""` or you can replace the double quotes inside the formula like using the as  `Chr(34) `.  34 is the ASCII code for a double quote.  e.ge. ` .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "=COUNTIF(G19:G121," & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & ")"`.

Comment: With the code we used above to make everything feed into the all projects page, all the dates that are empty feed in as 1/0/1900 is there anyway to make that not happen?

Comment: I'm not sure which cells have date values here is an example of how to modify the formula: `"=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11,TEXT(,))" `

Comment: I tried that , it didn't seem to work, my example would be for the material forecast , 30% actual, 60% actual, 90% actual, and in-service actual. I tried     '.Cells(x, "G").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11,TEXT(,))" for the material forecast

Comment: The problem is that the cells are formatted as dates.  Change the cells' format to percentage.

Comment: But the cell should be a date when you enter the information not a percentage... it is that there is no current input and when it transfer that to another sheet it autofills that "1/0/1900" date in

Comment: Format the cells as numbers and you'll see that the value of the cell is greater than 0 but less then 1.   Are you sure that your cell references are correct?